# Wi-fi drops connection every several hours

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

My router sometimes drops connection several times a day. I updated firmware but it didn't solve the problem.

I have to turn off / turn on router and it starts to work correctly again.

More details in case this will help:
Wifi is WPA2-PSK. Internet is a 4G usb stick that is plugged into my router.
Here's some settings from dashboard
[image]

I have 5 laptops, 1 wi-fi printer,  Microsoft wireless HDMI.

Here are some errors I see in my log. They appear from time to time.[image]

Other than that it just randomly stops working and I have to restart it.

Router: zyxel keenetic ultra

What is the best way to investigate such kind of problems?

Comment: It may just be an overloaded cell, have you checked with your ISP?

Comment: @Linef4ult, but then why it starts working file right after I restart router?

Comment: Cant say definitively as we dont have RADIUS/other logs that the ISP is using. If the modem sees fit to drop the link a reboot will usually bring it back up if available. Theres a reason why your ISP has a support dept, call them.